# Visual Studio: Solution-dependent formatting

Tags: visual-studio

Is it possible to change the way Visual Studio applies source-formatting, based on the loaded solution?

I work on several different solutions, for different customers, and they each have their own source-formatting standards.
As a developer it's frustrating to change the formatting rules every time I change solution, so is it somehow possible to store the source formatting settings in the solution file, or use some other program to handle the change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally use [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), which is a non-free commercial product, but has a trial version. It keeps my rules separate for each project, but allows me to merge settings too. One of the things it does is what you ask.